# Run tests with multiple versions and collect return values in Makefile

Tags: makefile, sh, gnu-make

I am developing Emacs package that runs from Emacs-22 to Emacs26, and I'd like to confirm that the test passes with these Emacs.

However, since each log is long, I would like to gather the return value of each test and display it clearly at the end.

How can I write this in Makefile? 
The list of Emacs to be tested has been obtained in `ALL_EMACS_VERS` as array (22.1 23.4 24.5 25.3 26.1), and now I am running the test as follows.

```
EMACS          ?= emacs
LOAD_PATH      := -L $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
BATCH          := $(EMACS) -Q --batch $(LOAD_PATH)
ALL_EMACS_VERS := $(shell compgen -c emacs- | grep -oP '(?<=emacs-)([0-9]|\.)+' | sort | uniq)

test:
    $(BATCH) -l srt-tests.el -f srt-run-tests

debug-localtest:
    for ver in $(ALL_EMACS_VERS); do \
        echo "===  test by emacs-$${ver}...  ==="; \
        EMACS=emacs-$${ver} make test; \
    done
```

I'd like to get information on which version the test passed, or did not pass, and output it as follows.

```
===  test by emacs-22.1  ===
emacs-22.1 -Q --batch -L ./ -l srt-tests.el -f srt-run-tests

Running 30 tests...
GNU Emacs 22.1.1 (mac-apple-darwin)
 of 2017-10-07 on osx339.sd.apple.com
[PASSED]  simple:equal
[PASSED]  simple:=
...

===== Run 30 Tests, 29 Expected, 1 Failed, 0 Errored =====

make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/conao/Develop/git/.dotfiles/.emacs.d/local/26.1/site-lisp/srt.el'


===  test by emacs-23.4  ===
emacs-23.4 -Q --batch -L ./ -l srt-tests.el -f srt-run-tests

Running 30 tests...
GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)
 of 2012-01-29 on bob.porkrind.org
[PASSED]  simple:equal
[PASSED]  simple:=
...

===== Run 30 Tests, 29 Expected, 1 Failed, 0 Errored =====

make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/conao/Develop/git/.dotfiles/.emacs.d/local/26.1/site-lisp/srt.el'

...
(Emacs 24.5, 25.3, 26.1)
...

===  localtest completed!!  ===

*FAILED* Emacs-22.1
*FAILED* Emacs-23.4
[PASSED] Emacs-24.5
*FAILED* Emacs-25.3
[PASSED] Emacs-26.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has two parts. The first is to give the desired output for one test. If (as the title of your Question suggests) this depends on the return value of the process, this approach will work:

```
single-test:
    (some-command && echo PASS) || echo FAIL
```

In your case, this becomes:

```
ARGS := -Q --batch $(LOAD_PATH) -l srt-tests.el -f srt-run-tests

test-emacs-22.1:
    (emacs-22.1 $(ARGS) && echo [PASS] emacs-22.1) || echo *FAIL* emacs-22.1
```

The second part is to iterate over a list of versions. I suggest using a pattern rule:

```
ALL_EMACS_VERS := 22.1 23.4 24.5 25.3 26.1
TESTS := $(addprefix test-emacs-, $(ALL_EMACS_VERS))

all-tests: $(TESTS)

test-%:
    ($* $(ARGS) && echo [PASS] $*) || echo *FAIL* $*
```

Finally, if these processes produce output you wish to suppress:

```
test-%:
    ($* $(ARGS) > /dev/null && echo [PASS] $*) || echo *FAIL* $*
```

**EDIT:** To print all of the results after all of the script output, the simplest approach is to save them in a file, called e.g. "results":

```
all-tests: $(TESTS)
    @cat results
    @rm results

test-%:
    @($* $(ARGS) && echo [PASS] $* >> results) || echo *FAIL* $* >> results
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I could not think of a way to define a job like this.
However, I do not want to discard the log of each test (although my question was not well written).

I edited the question so I would be happy to see it.

Comment: @NaoyaYamashita: it is now unclear what each emacs process should produce.

Comment: What is unclear?  I do not want to discard Emacs's all output log, and show test summary at once.

Comment: @Conao3: Then what is the problem? My solution works.

Comment: Yes you did. But your solution is discard Emacs detail test log (such as `simple:equal` is pass,, etc.)

Comment: Do not output to `/dev/null` will get (testlog-for-22), ([pass] emacs-22), (testlog-for-23), ([pass] emacs-23)... But I want to get (test-for-22), (test-for-23),,, ([pass] emacs-22), ([pass] emacs-23),,, is .